# Load jQuery in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm writing a script which requires some stuff to be carried out in an iframe. It's a userscript for a site which I do not own, so because of cross-domain issues, I cannot just set the `src` of the `iframe` to a page with my own code. Instead, I am dynamically building the iframe.

To do this, I have

```
 function childScripts(){
  //Stuff that must be injected into the iframe.
  //Needs jQuery
 }


 //because I'm lazy:
 var iframeWin=$('#my-iframe')[0].contentWindow;

 //Load jQuery:
 var script = iframeWin.document.createElement("script");
 script.type = "text/javascript";
 script.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
 iframeWin.document.head.appendChild(script);

 //Inject script
 var script = iframeWin.document.createElement("script");
 script.type = "text/javascript";
 script.textContent="("+childScripts.toString()+")()";
 iframeWin.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Now, the injected script needs jQuery, but for some reason, jQuery isn't loaded when the injected script runs--even though jQuery is in `<head>` and the injected script is in  `<body>`.

I've tried other workarounds--making the injected script run `onload`. I don't like the idea of setting a timeout and checking for the existence of jQuery, I'd prefer a more elegant solution.

I've also tried copying the `$` object to `iframeWin.$`, but of course that doesn't work, since it just backreferences to the parent `$` and manipulates the parent document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to manipulate iframes using jQuery. Please try:

```
$('<iframe id="my-iframe"/>').load(function(){
  $('#my-iframe').contents().find('body').append('asd').end()
                            .find('body').append('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>').end()
                            .find('body').append('<script>$(function() {alert("hello from jquery");console.log("hello from jquery"); })<\/script>');                             

}).appendTo("body");
```

Placement:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $('<iframe id="my-iframe"/>').load(function(){..... 
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: you can ignore `'asd'`, forgot to remove it. i used that for testing the iframe before i inserted the script tags.

Comment: For some reason the scripts aren't being appended at _all_. If I remove the `load`, then stuff is appended--but the scripts are still stripped out. O_0

Comment: I believe it's because you placed the iframe load call inside the head tag. It should be before the closing body. Also don't forget to put your jquery script call before it: 

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('<iframe id="my-iframe"/>').load(function(){.....
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: I'm running it via the JS console. Text is appended, but the scripts aren't. The scripts still _do_ run, but in the parent window. Anyway, I'll experiment a bit and get back to you. A mix of your approach and mine may help..

Comment: Alright, I threw in the towel and used `setTimeout`. :/ Though I _could_ have just done `iframewin.$=$('#iframewin').find.
`